# Starting iPad app in current landscape orientation

Tags: ipad, orientation, landscape

My ipad app only runs in landscape orientation. But when I test on an actual device (not the simulator) it always seem to start in one particular landscape orientation, then turn 180 degrees to match the current physical landscape orientation.  So, it seems to start in LandscapeLeft(I think) then rotate 180 if I have it in LandscapeRight.  There's nothing in Info.plist to set the initial orientation.

Can anyone suggest a way to detect current orientation before view loads and set it to correct landscape view before showing?

Thanks

Fitto

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this, but I'm upvoting it because it's a good beginner question and the answer isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `UIInterfaceOrientation~iPad` key which sets the initial interface orientation on startup.

There is also the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key which informs the app which orientations are supported.

There is no way, however, to make the app start in the current orientation of the iPad.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I suspected. Just needed confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into these questions?

- [Get current orientation of iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738734/get-current-orientation-of-ipad)
- [iPad launch orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859516/ipad-launch-orientation)

Also, technically, the iPad should just do it. Make sure you have supported orientations set properly, as I'm sure it checks those to see where it should start.