# notification banner on ipad displayed upside down when app is launching Landscape (left home button)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5, apple-push-notifications

I had an iPad app that supports two Orientation I set Supported interface orientations on info.plist to Landscape (right home button) and Landscape (left home button). I also set Initial interface orientation to Landscape (right home button).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
}
```

When I receive push notification and my app is closed. And I started the app not from notification. The notification banner appears up-side down. This happens only when I'm holding ipad on Landscape (left home button). Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same issue and tried many ways;
In my app I require only landscape orientation so I set

`return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);`

in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` of every `ViewController`

and in `info.plist` for supported interface orientation I am setting

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

This solved my problem.